# Granger causality result interpretation in R

Tags: r, time-series, granger-causality, f-statistic

I am unable to interpret what this means.T2 is a `zoo` object containing two two price series. `MSBVAR` library of `R` is used.

http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MSBVAR/MSBVAR.pdf

```
granger.test(T2, p=4)  
                             F-statistic               p-value  
bse_price -> nse_price  19.4113269112582 5.551115123125783e-16  
nse_price -> bse_price 220.4466683121889 0.000000000000000e+00
```

A view of data:

```
head(T2)  
      tstamp        nse_price bse_price  
1425354300.6811     347.85   348.775  
1425354300.68114    347.85   348.775  
1425354300.68116    347.85   348.775  
1425354300.6909     347.85   348.350  
1425354300.80537    347.85   348.375  
1425354300.92212    347.85   348.375
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The F-statistics and the associated p-values tell you something about the null hypothesis, which is that there is **no** Granger causality. In both cases, the p-values are so small that you would **reject** the null hypothesis of **no** Granger causality at any usual level of significance.